# Printer service not available

Tags: printing

Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Since installing a recent system update a week or so ago, cups does not start automatically and the start service button is grayed out.
I've reinstalled cups, but on reboot or wake-up I have to manually start the service from the terminal using the command:

```
$ sudo service cups restart
```

This works, and I'm able to see and print to all the installed printers, but it's a pain. I'm not certain that the update caused this problem, but I haven't changed any system configurations or installed any new software or hardware (including printers).
Any help to resolve this problem so that cups starts automatically as it used to would be GREATLY appreciated!
 Thanks in advance, Susan

Comment: Log files are in `/var/log/cups`. Especially `error_log` may be of interest.

Comment: Please [edit] into your post the output of `lsb_release -a` to help alleviate the confusion (at least I'm experiencing. ) Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: sorry for not providing more information, I'm fairly new to Linux so I provided as much info as I knew how to get.  Thanks for the great info - good to know! I resolved it by uninstalling, purge, and then reinstalling it and it seems to be working now. Still don't know why it "broke" but it's fixed and that's good enough for me :) thanks for the quick response too - you rock!